# How to assign variable to Object Property in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ole

I'm trying to set `namespace` property from `Shell.Application` object dynamically.

```
With CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace(FolderName)
    ExtendProperty = .GetDetailsOf(.Items.Item(FileName), 143)
End With
```

When values for `FolderName` and for `FileName` are fixed(hard coded) snippet is working. But when I try to pass them in as a variables; error `Run-time error 91 - Object variable or With Block variable not set.` is returning. Also I need to assign returned value to variable for later use; `ExtendProperty`. I'm a bit new to VBA and could not find anything on the internet(Scopes, locals, etc.) for this specific case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid the error mentioned pass variables as variants

```
Sub TEST2()
    Dim ExtendProperty As Variant
    Dim folderName As Variant, FileName As Variant
    folderName = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\TestFolder"
    FileName = "Test.xlsx"
    With CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace(folderName)
       ExtendProperty = .GetDetailsOf(.Items.item(FileName), 143)
    End With
End Sub
```